# Undefined variables in `if` statement

Tags: autohotkey

This will work as expected:

```
a := "111"
b := "222"

if (a != "aaa" and b != "bbb")
    MsgBox, Yes
```

But the "Yes" message will be also shown if one of the variables is not defined

```
; a := "111" ; Commented line
b := "222"

if (a != "aaa" and b != "bbb")
    MsgBox, Yes ; Since var "a" is not defined, I don't want this message box
```

Here is how I fix it:

```
; a := "111"
b := "222"

if ((a and b) and (a != "aaa" and b != "bbb"))
    MsgBox, Yes
```

But from my point of view it looks like something awful. Is there exist more correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `and` is commutative, you can do without the parentheses:

```
if a and b and a != "aaa" and b != "bbb"
```

**ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION**

Initialize your variables to the value you're testing (aaa) so that if your implementation code doesn't alter them, you'll get the desired result:

```
a=aaa
b=bbb

... do some stuff ...

global a,b
if a != "aaa" and b != "bbb"
    MsgBox, Yes
```

---

EXPLANATION

When `a` is `undefined`, it seems like you want `undefined != "aaa"` to somehow evaluate to `false`.  That's the same as saying you you want `undefined == "aaa"` to somehow evaluate to `true`.  Your logic is too complex for that.

Here's a state table for your logic:

```
                Actual  Desired T1      T2
a       b       MsgBox  MsgBox  a!=aaa  b!=bbb  T1 and T2
-----   ------  ------  ------- ------  ------  -----
undef   undef   Yes     no      true    true    true 
undef   bbb     no      no      true    false   false
undef   222     Yes     no      true    true    true    The example you didn't want
aaa     undef   no      no      false   true    false  
aaa     bbb     no      no      false   false   false
aaa     222     no      no      false   true    false
111     undef   Yes     no      true    true    true
111     bbb     no      no      true    false   false
111     222     Yes     Yes     true    true    true    Only one you want
```

The `Actual MsgBox` column shows when the message box appears in your original code. `Desired MsgBox`=Yes is what you wanted to happen. `T1` and `T2` are the partial calculations of your condition. `T1 and T2` is the final value of your condition.

The last row shows the only state in which you want the MsgBox to appear; when `a` is equal to niether `aaa` nor `undefined` AND `b` is equal to neither `bbb` nor `undefined`.

So we can simplify the logic by initializing `a` to "aaa" and `b` to "bbb".  In effect we are combining your the two conditions for each variable into a single condition by making the two values ("aaa" and `undefined`) equivalent.

I hope that makes sense

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my question was about how to avoid message if one of variables is not defined. In your example, if I comment out first line (`; a=aaa`), the message will be still shown. That is not what I want. **Update:** Oh, sorry, your actual answer was `if a and b and a != "aaa" and b != "bbb"`, and the second code block is just an addition, right?

Comment: the second code block was an alternative solution. i added an explanation